# Re-running a python code with a while loop

Tags: python, error-handling, while-loop, compiler-errors, output

How could I write a piece of code that recognizes if the any type of error has occurred and if it does the code just runs on a loop. What would be a function that I would place in `<some error occurs>` so it recognizes any error 0utput and re runs the code within 10 seconds.

```
while True:
    <all your code>

    if <some error occurs>:
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `try...except`

```
while True:
    try:
        <all_your_code>
    except:
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
```

Read this for better understanding: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling